# Calling Table-valued Function with inline convert parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an error in some sql server installation while calling a Table-valued Function and try to convert the parameter inline.

```
SELECT *
FROM myFunction(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @value1))
```

The error returned is
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.`

The function works without Convert.

```
SELECT *
FROM myFunction(@value2)
```

the sql server version is

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr 2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 (Build 9200: )

Is there any setting to fix it ?

Comment: *"I have an error"* And what is that error? The fact that you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 is a problem undo it's own, it has been completely out of support since 2018, however, the fact that you are using the RTM version is alarming. This means you haven't installed a *single* security update or bug fix on your host in *almost* **13 years**... Not upgrading your instance for over 3 years after it's no longer supported is one problem but **never bothering to install single update** is outright foolishness.

Comment: sorry the error is 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.'

Comment: This works fine. https://dbfiddle.uk/MRcVVffp I don't remember if syntax rules were stricter in 2008 days and it behaved like stored procedure parameters (that don't allow expressions)

Comment: @Larnu is right about his consideration, it's worth noting that some decisions are out of a dev scope

Comment: @Larnu i know it's an old version but i can't update it, it not mine server and i can't manage it

Comment: Then get whomever is responsible to at least install the last **decade's** worth of updates, @MERCCK , while they work out their upgrade path (which they should have finalised writing some time ago). Step one of debugging is installing updates on the service; you have over *8 years* of missing bug fixes to install. That syntax certainly works in "recent" *supported* versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Does `SELECT f.* FROM (values (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @value1))) v(conv) CROSS APPLY myFunction(conv) f` work?

Comment: @MartinSmith No, the remote server return ' "conv" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.' On my local sql server installation works

Comment: And what is the database compatibility mode set to?

Comment: @MartinSmith the database compatibility is set to 80

Comment: That's SQL Server 2000, @MERCCK . No wonder what you have isn't working. The syntax you are using simply wasn't supported ~23 years ago.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to contact the admin if he can alter the compatibility level of the database

Comment: I assume it will probably be like that for some reason. Potentially using deprecated outer join syntax that only works at that compat for example

Comment: In truth, it sounds like you have some very different tasks you need to address: **1.** Get the last 12~ years of updates installed on the instance (and host, presumably, as I suspect Windows is also very out of date is SQL Server is). **2.** Review the code on the instance and ensure it's not using any deprecated/discontinued features from SQL Server 2000/2005/2008 and make changes accordingly. **3.** Update the compatibility level of the database to 100. **4.** Get the instance upgraded to a (ideally fully) supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: **5.** Review the objects again, and update any that use deprecated/discontinued feature from SQL Server 2012-{New Version} and update accordingly. **6.** Debug the above code is still required (unlikely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinSmith and @Larnu.

The problem was due by the database compatibility mode set to 80 (SQL Server 2000)